# SlideToggle not working correctly after using .load (ajax)

Tags: jquery

I am experimenting with a custom lightbox effect and am finding it is quite complicated. The experience is getting more refined but I have found once I load the modal window (contact) and remove it all instances of slideToggle no longer work correctly.

This is the code: (not sure this really helps)

```
$('.viewinfo').on( 'click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('.project').find('.project-info').slideToggle(1500, 'easeOutCubic');
        $(this).toggleClass('closeinfo');
    });

$('#icon-mobile-menu').on('click', function(){
        $('#mobile-nav ul').slideToggle(1500);
    });
```

I am still new to jquery so there is much I don't understand...
Any help is greatly appreciated

[View Site](http://www.evoke.me)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to this instead (delegated click event perhaps):

Get rid of the easing effect and see if that causes the problem to go away for now:

```
$('body').on( 'click', '.viewinfo', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('.project').find('.project-info').slideToggle(1500);
        $(this).toggleClass('closeinfo');
    });

$('body').on('click', '#icon-mobile-menu', function(){
        $('#mobile-nav ul').slideToggle(1500);
    });
```

Technically, you should use the immediate parent that is constant for the element and not `body`, but `body` will work also.

Hope I'm understanding you correctly.  Let me know if this helps any...

Comment: maybe both need to be `$('body')` do the elements still exist in the HTML after you remove the modal window (contact), do these elements still exist in the DOM:  `.viewinfo` and/or `#icon-mobile-menu`?  You can inspect the webpage after removing the modal window to see if they still exist or not.

Comment: Yes they do. You can see for yourself with the link above... I'm doing a lot with this page so I'm beginning to find conflicts..

Comment: There is an error on that page after you remove the contact modal window, and it says this:  `Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'st.easing[this.easing]' is not a function` and is assigned to the `click` event of that button, but it's not related to the code I posted.  It's something else entirely different.

Comment: Actually, I believe it is related to `'easeOutCubic'` call within the `slideToggle` of the click event.  Try removing that and it will probably work!

Comment: I am finding that each time I load the modal a number of classes are added to the html tag. These classes seem to be repeated each time. I am  wondering if that is the problem... I tried commenting out the modernizr script which I thought generated those classes but still they show up.